# Enemy life and bullet power unity3d c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new at Unity. I have successfully made a player can shoot a bullet to the enemy depends on the current wave, and I make where the enemy have it is own life depends on the current wave multiply with certain value. If the enemy life is 0, the enemy dies. But, the problem is: for example there are 2 enemies on the scene and the enemy life is 5 and the player start shooting the first enemy until the enemy life decreases to 2, when the player start shooting the second enemy, the enemy life is not 5 anymore, but it is 2 until one of the 2 cubes is dead and the enemy life reset to 5.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the bullet script:

```
public class BulletManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
private ScoreManager scoreManager;

private PlayerController playerController;

private EnemyManager enemyManager;

public int bulletPower;

private void Start()
{
    scoreManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<ScoreManager>();

    playerController = GameObject.Find("Character").GetComponent<PlayerController>();

    enemyManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<EnemyManager>();

    bulletPower = playerController.currentWave;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        enemyManager.enemyLife -= bulletPower;

        if (enemyManager.enemyLife <= 0)
        {
            scoreManager.Points += (2 * playerController.currentWave);

            enemyManager.enemyLife = playerController.currentWave * 5;

            Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the enemy script:

```
public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
private ScoreManager scoreManager;

private SoundManager soundManager;

private PlayerController playerController;

public int enemyLife;

private void Start()
{
    scoreManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<ScoreManager>();

    soundManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<SoundManager>();

    playerController = GameObject.Find("Character").GetComponent<PlayerController>();

    enemyLife = playerController.currentWave * 5;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (playerController.life <= 0)
    {
        Invoke("Restart", 1);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        soundManager.PlaySound("Enemy Dead");

        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }

    else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Destroyer")
    {
        playerController.life--;
    }
}

private void Restart()
{
    scoreManager.SendToHighScore();

    Application.LoadLevel(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Does each enemy have its own script attached or is the enemy manager script attached to something else? What i would do is have a script attached to the enemy to hold the variable for its remaining life.

Comment: Each of enemy only have a EnemyManager script attached and also in the empty object called GameManager. So, what did you suggest is create a script that hold the enemy life and attach it to the enemy?

Comment: You should give each enemy a script that manages its health and everything that is connected to the health, like dieing for example. The management of health should not be a part of the GameManager, since a class called "GameManager" should only manage game parts like score, resetting, saving, loading etc. Also, GameObject.Find() is a very slow operation and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all of your enemies use the EnemyManager class to manage their health. What your code does is count the amount of hits on all enemies and then destroys the last one that was hit. My suggestion is to add an EnemyStats class to manage stats specific to each enemy (name of the enemy, the amount of damage they can do, weapon graphics, sound effects, the skys the limit). I hate to give you the answer right off the bat (or at least a basic one) since this is a good learning opportunity but here is a basic script that should do what you need and the changes you need to make to your BulletManager script.

**EnemyStats.cs** (Attach to the enemies game object)

```
public class EnemyStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentHealth;
    public int maxHealth;
    public float increasePerWave;
    public int bulletPower;

    // use a negative value for healing
    public void ReduceHealth(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
    }

    public bool IsDead()
    {
        return currentHealth <= 0;
    }

    public int GetDamage()
    {
        return bulletPower;
    }

    /// Restores enemy to their max health for the current wave. Call this after creating an spawning.
    public void RestoreHealth(int wave)
    {
        currentHealth = (int)(maxHealth * increasePerWave * (wave + 1));
    }
}
```

**BulletManager** update

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        EnemyStats stats = col.GetComponent<EnemyStats>();

        if (stats)
        {
            stats.ReduceHealth(bulletPower);

            if (stats.IsDead())
            {
                scoreManager.Points += (2 * playerController.currentWave);
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```